# Unmerge in GIT with 3 branches

Tags: git, revert

I have searched but all examples I have found only involves 2 branches.
We have 3 branches

- Master (m)
- Develop (d)
- Feature (f)

Where the feature branch is supposed to be merged directly into master but there is a merge from develop into the feature branch that should not be there.

> ```
>                             1       2
> f            *----c---------*--c----*
>             /              /         \              3
> m *--------*--------------/-----------*---   ------*
>    \                     /                        /
> d   *---------c-------c-*-----c-----------   ----*
> ```

What will happen if I revert commit 1 from develop inte feature? Will I lose parts of develop on commit 3?

To clarify #2 is not done yet there is just a PR at that stage now.

Comment: The `git revert <id>` command doesn't rewrite history like some other git commands.  It's simply a convenient way to create a new commit out of the difference between `<id>` and its parent.

Comment: Wouldn't that mean the first 2 c:s on the develop branch be lost?

Comment: You say that 2 is still just a pull request. What does the line from "2" into branch "m" mean, then? And if that is not an actual merge, is then the line at "3" from branch "d" to "m" an existing merge or just a pull request? But then the line from branch "d" to point "1" *is* an existing merge?

Answer (score 0):

Nice mess-up you dug yourself into, huh!

There is a **direct** later merge of `develop` into `master` so it's not like you included something in `master` from `develop` that should not be there.... in this case, if there is something *real* to gain, it would only be *cosmetic* to clean up history of your feature branch... *and* if you went ahead to remove that merge commit (which is possible.... by rewriting history), it would *also* require rewriting history of `master` to get it *really* cleaned up so.... there is no practical gain in trying to clean it up. Live with it.... unless you really *really* **really** want to rewrite history of `master` (which should be a show-stopper right there).

If `develop` were **not** merged into `master` then *that* would be a nice case to study.

Comment: Yes it is a mess but sometimes you, as we say in swedish put "your foot in the accordion". And as I clarified the feature branch is not merged into master yet. There is only a PR, thats where it was discovered.

Comment: Yeah.... tell me about it! :-D

Answer (score 0):

We solved it by creating a new branch, cherrypick commits from the messy branch and then ditching it.

By the way, thanks for all the suggestions.